# How can i, after a time x, send me a message with the amount of emojis of a message

Tags: discord.js

How can i, after a time x, send me a message with the amount of emojis of a message. for example
5 reactions to the emoji: 
6 reactions to the emoji:

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```js
message.channel.send('message').then(async (msg) => { // send the message
  setTimeout(() => { // use the setTimeout function to add a delay before executing
    switch (msg.reactions.cache.size) { // get the number of emojis reacted
      case 1: { // if there was 1 emoji:
        message.channel.send('something');
        break;
      }
      case 2: { // if there was 2:
        message.channel.send('something2');
        break;
      }
      case 3: { // if there was 3:
        message.channel.send('something3');
        break;
      }

      // etc.
    }
    console.log(`${msg.reactions.cache.size} emojis were reacted.`);
  }, 10000); // execute after whatever time (in milliseconds) you prefer, I'm using 10000 (10 seconds) as an example
});
```

---

After you get the number of emojis reacted ([`<message>.reactions.cache.size`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction)), you can do anything you want with it, I was just using the [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement as an example.

You also don't have to use the [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function, it's just the easiest way to trigger something after a delay. For example, you could trigger after an [`event`](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_events.asp), or anything else you might want.

Comment: I just realized you meant emojis in the message, not reactions. LOL.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming things right now cause for one I don't exactly get what you are trying to say and two, you are being a bit vague without giving any already existing code.

If the bot should send you the message only when a message with emojis is sent then all you have to do is, in your message event, check if the message contains an emoji. A simple regular expression would do: `const emojiRegex = /<:[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}:\d{18}>/ig;`. Then check if the message contains any match.

```js
const matches = message.content.match(emojiRegex);
if (matches) {
     const owner = client.users.cache.get('user_id'); // enter your user id
     owner.send(`There have been ${matches.length} emojis in message \`${message.id}\` at ${message.url}`);
}
```